# Combine multiple errors handling

Tags: swift, error-handling, combine

I decided to migrate a standard network call to one using combine and its operators.

Given the following code

```
enum NetworkServiceError: Error{
   case badUrl
   case networkFail(String)
}

func getHtml(from url: String, completion: @escaping (Result<String, NetworkServiceError>) -> ()) {
   guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
      completion(.failure(.badUrl))
      return
   }
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
      if let err = error{
         completion(.failure(.networkFail(err.localizedDescription)))
         return
      }
      guard let rawHtmlData = data else {
         completion(.failure(.networkFail("No data")))
         return
      }
      guard let html = String(data: rawHtmlData, encoding: .utf8) else {
         completion(.failure(.networkFail("String serialization failed")))
         return
      }
      completion(.success(html))
   }
   .resume()
}
```

I would like to have the same precise error handling in the combine counterpart.
Being honest, i can t figure out how to do so despite i watched tons of videos about combine.
Here is my attempt

```
func combineHtml(url: String)-> AnyPublisher<String, NetworkServiceError>{
   
   guard let safeUrl = URL(string: url) else {
      return Fail(error: NetworkServiceError.badUrl).eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }

   let publisher = URLSession.shared
      .dataTaskPublisher(for: safeUrl)
      .tryMap{ result-> Data in
         guard !result.data.isEmpty else{throw NetworkServiceError.networkFail("No data")}
         return result.data
      }
      .tryMap{ data-> String in
         guard let html = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else{
            throw NetworkServiceError.networkFail("String serialization failed")
         }
         return html
      }
//      .mapError{ error-> NetworkServiceError in
//         return NetworkServiceError.networkFail("error")
//      }

 
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      
   return publisher
      
}
```

Im not sure how i should handle the different errors: the try operators should throw and the pipeline should cancel, which is what i want. However, if i dont map the error to NetworkServiceError, (commented code) i should change the return type which i d like to avoid.
There must be something which is not correct im my error handling.

What would be the best way to handle multiple errors in combine?
Im not really satisfied with this code.

Comment: What's the problem with mapping the error? `tryMap`'s failure type is `Error` because it doesn't restrict the error that could be thrown, so you need to map the error to the error type you expect, for example with `.mapError { $0 as! NetworkServiceError }` (try to avoid force casting)

Comment: @NewDev The problem is mismatching type, as i need to work on NetworkServiceError and not just Error: if you check the tryMap blocks, i throw different errors inside. This helps me understand what failed: inside the mapError, i dont have such informations, so i would end up just mapping an error with no clue about of what s occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this.
I will post relevant parts of the code, the rest is unchanged

```
.tryMap{ result-> String in
         guard !result.data.isEmpty else{throw NetworkServiceError.networkFail("No data")}
         guard let html = String(data: result.data, encoding: .utf8) else{
            throw NetworkServiceError.networkFail("String serialization failed")
         }
         return html
      }
.mapError{error-> NetworkServiceError in
   if let customError = error as? NetworkServiceError{
       return customError
    }
    return NetworkServiceError.networkFail(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The mapError operator is necessary to accomplish type requirement. In the tryMap we can throw all the needed errors, as we will catch them in the mapError closure